# can't install opencv on my pi

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3b+, opencv, pip

I'm an absolute Raspberry Pi newbie. My intention is to get some camera vision project working for which I need `OpenCV3.3`'s `dnn` `Python` module.

I've found [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/) a description of how `OpenCV` can be installed with `pip` but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python
```

can anyone help me further here?

Comment: Are you running Raspbian Stretch or an older version? On Stretch I would expect it to work for python3/pip3. Had a quick look at the tutorial and it seems to be incomplete/incorrect: AFAIK there is not yet a binary version of opencv for Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python3-opencv
```

You might try also to compile the library by yourself by downloading the source code from the [git repository](https://opencv.org/releases.html). Note that from the link a version 4 is available. You will have to solve a lot of dependencies by yourself by installing `apt` packages.

Raspberry3 model B should have enough memory to compile it (it requires a lot of time) (RPi2 maybe, RPi1 I do not think so) but it's not garanteed. If I remember correctly I compiled it but after a couple of times it went out of memory).

In this link [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/) is described a much longer step-by-step tutorial for Ubuntu and [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/) specific for the raspberry to compile the library opencv by yourself but I think the first command is enough and dependencies should be installed automatically (if it works on aspbian).

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to compile - there should be a package in the repository.
I have never used it, but `apt-cache search opencv` will show all the candidates.

I expect `sudo apt install python-opencv` is what you want.

If you are a beginner you almost certainly don't want the `contrib` package.

Comment: The Problem is, the repo only contains`opencv 2.4` and I need >=`3.3` as I require `dnn` (which only got introduced with 3.3)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up compiling OpenCV 3.4.4 from source as described on https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/ - the instructions are for Ubuntu but it worked just fine the same way on my Rasperry Pi running `Raspian 9`. I ended up with:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.4.4'
>>> quit()
```